# Are the following sentences correct/idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, vocabulary

"I'll see you at the top of the x street/alley."
"I'm at the bottom of the x street/alley."

Or should we just say "at/around the corner of the x street"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to say "...at the top of the street" if the street is on a hill; if it is flat then it doesn't have a top or a bottom, though you could say "at the North end of the street" or something similar.

Or if you and your companion have been walking along a street you could just say "the end of the street" and it would be assumed you mean the end you've been walking towards.

Note that if you're using the street's name then you wouldn't say "the", you would say (for example) "...at the top of Smith Street" or "...at the corner of Smith and Scott streets".